# Obfuscating SharpDX assemblies

Tags: obfuscation, sharpdx

I have built my own slightly modified SharpDX assemblies and they work fine when I don't obfuscate them (using Crypto Obfuscator). When I obfuscate them I get this error message:

The type or namespace name 'FunctionCallback' does not exist in the namespace 'SharpDX' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have also strong-name signed the assemblies in each project's AssemblyInfo.cs. Same key is used during obfuscation.

ShapCLI executable is called in post-build event and it seem to inject some code in each assembly. Does obfuscation mess this up since class/type etc. names are changed?

Has anyone else had this problem? I really need a solution asap... :/

Thanks in advance.

Forgot to mention that my SharpDX DirectX assembly builds just fine even with obfuscation but when I try to build e.g. DirectSound assembly (which references to DirectX) build fails. Everyone probably already knows this but I thought to bring it up just in case. I'm learning this while doing. :)

Comment: You should contact Crypto Obfuscator directly and provide them your solution (our reproduce it with a simple SharpDX sample) as it sounds more a bug in their product. FunctionCallback is an internal type in SharpDX assembly. SharpCLI should run before obfuscation, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you reply. I went through the settings of my obfuscation project and when I turned "symbol renaming" off, my DirectSound assembly was build without any problems. I'm not sure if disabling that feature is a good idea but at least it builds now. Haven't tested the assembly with my main application yet though. I also tried to add some obfuscation rules that would skip FunctionCallback but that didn't work.